# How to make an adaptive form(email input box) with a submit button next to input area?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make an adaptive form:

[image]

I managed to kinda make it but it's a nightmare to edit it and not really that adaptive:

```
<div class="widget">
    <h2>Stay Tuned.</h2>
    <div class="subscribe">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" class="subscribe-input">
            <input type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/7pyyReI.png" class="subscribe-image">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #6c6969;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-left: 2px solid #58c93a;
    padding: 17px 0 21px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.subscribe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.subscribe-input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #b9b9b9;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #e1e0e0;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.subscribe-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #b9b9b9;
}

.subscribe-image {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cq8q0y61/

Is there a solution which is easy to edit and more adaptive than this one? I would like to not be forced to set height of .subscribe class manually, to be able to change on the fly font size, paddings and margins of .subscribe-input class and to be able to change on the fly that button-image to another image(with another height and width), so that input text and a button are still vertically centered and so that input text doesn't go over the button.

After doing some more digging I found how to make it better using flex method:
https://jsfiddle.net/t3LLcu35/2/

But I still have a problem: when I set vertical paddings or margins for .subscribe-input class, image is stretched:

```
.subscribe-input {
     padding: 50px 2px 50px 20px;
}
```

[image]

How to change margins and padding for .subscribe-input without stretching the image?

Comment: The first jsfiddle is utterly confusing, with the screenshot of itself as the image.

Comment: @MrLister, do you mean last image(which is a screenshot of the second jsfiddle in the question) in the question? I changed it to a code and a screenshot of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second fiddle looks ok, besides that you have `display:flex` for the wrapper and the form. Remove it for the wrapper "subscribe". (Sidenote: Even better would be, giving the form an id or class and refer to it in the css)

And then to your problem: There is a flex-propety called `align-items`, which will align the items of the flex-container perpendicular to the main-axis. Here you have to give the form `align-items: center`.

I find [this guide from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) pretty good for understanding flex.

Comment: Now I am wondering how can I make it so it doesn't stretch the image when I set big paddings for:
.subscribe-input {
     padding: 50px 2px 50px 20px;
}

For example, if I set big paddings for the image itself, it works just fine and centers the input box:
.subscribe-image {
    padding: 25px 20px 25px 0px;
}

But as I said before, if I set paddings for .subscribe-input, it stretches image instead of just centering it.

The idea is to be able to change paddings/margins of one input element without editing all other elements in the form.

Comment: Read the answer and apply it to your problem. It will work. I have modify your fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/8x5mk271/ I don't see your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ok, so problem was in align-items: center;. I added it and now it works. I don't really understand how it works, so I guess I'll go and read that article.